# How to migrate from Gradle to Kobalt?

Tags: java, build, kotlin

Kobalt is a new build tool for java written in Kotlin. As you may already know, migrating from Maven to Gradle is very easy! How can I convert my Gradle project into Kobalt? --init does not do the task!

Comment: Why do people give minus to such a valid question?  I think SO must punish them!

Comment: I don't think anyone must be punished here. What makes you think the migration from grade to kobalt can be automated?

Comment: @f1sh Since from Maven to Gradle is automated (and vice versa) Why not? Both are build engines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, (7/5/2017) Kobalt's [todo list](https://github.com/cbeust/kobalt/blob/master/TODO.md) has an entry for implementing import of `build.gradle` dependencies. As you noted, this is a fairly new tool, and as such, many of the more advanced features are not yet completed.

Comment: Sure! But keep in mind many users like me wanna give Kobalt a try, and they are already using Maven/Gradle. IMHO this feature is vital!